# How to unit test Riverpod StateNotifier using ProviderContainer

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-test, riverpod

I want to test Riverpod `StateNotifierProvider`. I'm trying to follow a TDD approach for state notifier providers without implementing UI/Widgets.

According to `Riverpod` documentation on testing, can use `ProviderContainer` for testing without Widget test. But it doesn't work the way I want.

Scenario :
When call function in the provider several state changes happen in order.

Objective :
Track all states. Ensure all state changes are in the correct order.

My question :

What's the best way to test these `StateNotifierProvider` state changes without implementing UI/Widget.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example about how to use `ProviderContainer` to track mock state changes from a state notifier provider.

```dart
// The provider mock class
class MyProviderMock extends StateNotifier<MyProviderState> with Mock implements MyProvider {
  MyProviderMock() : super(MyProviderInitialState());
}

// A generic Listener class, used to keep track of when a provider notifies its listeners
class Listener<T> extends Mock {
  void call(T? previous, T next);
}

void main() {
  final providerMock = MyProviderMock();
  
  test('states are emitted in sequence', () {
    final container = ProviderContainer(
        overrides: [
          myProviderReference.overrideWith((ref) => providerMock),
        ],
      );
    final listener = ListenerMock<MyProviderState>();
    container.listen<MyProviderState>(myProviderReference, listener, fireImmediately: true);

      verifyInOrder(
        [
          () => listener(null, MyProviderLoadingState()),
          () => listener(MyProviderLoadingState(), MyProviderLoadedState()),
          () => listener(MyProviderLoadedState(), AnyOtherState()),
        ],
      );

      verifyNoMoreInteractions(listener);
  }

}
```

Full ref of the example above: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/unit-test-async-notifier-riverpod/

Comment: @Yunnosch Updated the answer by adding an example and the reference to the source

Comment: Thanks, I think that is how it gets to be an answer. Have fun.